# Accessing session scoped variable in JSTL when <%@page session="false" %>

Tags: java, session, servlets, jstl

I have two questions,

1. Can I access the session scoped variables using JSTL tags when the JSP is having `<%@page session="false" %>`. In my web application, I am creating a new session from servlet upon login, using `request.getSession()` and setting the attributes thereafter. However my JSP pages do not include `<%@ page session="false" %>` and I am using JSTL tags to display data stored in session and request. After debugging, I can see that new sessions are getting created randomly. If I add `<%@ page session="false" %>` to the JSP pages to ensure new sessions are not created, will there be any impact?
2. Also, I have set a timeout of 15 mins in web.xml. Normally my application times out if there is more than 15 mins of inactivity. But occasionally, it times out in 1 or 2 minutes. I am not understanding this weird behavior. Is this related to new sessions being created. When it times out, I have seen that a new session with different session id gets created. In my code, I am detecting a timeout as follows,

   ```
   if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
       && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
       // redirect to a login page with a message
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you write the directive `<%@page session="false" %>` in a JSP, this takes out the line  `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` from its auto-generated servlet's java source code. So no, you can't access session info in the page if you don't grab it in the first place.
2. It would be ok if it timed out after a longer time than the one set in the web.xml, but not if it times out earlier. There must be something something in your app that you don't think about, like a call to a `session.invalidate()` somewhere.